# Android style forms - I have a issue with stylng lables

Tags: android, html, css

I have tried to create android style forms for a project me and a few mates are working on.

I have managed to get the text input field to change style when I have wanted it to. But I can not manage to get the related labels to change colour.

This is what I'm going for:

[image]

can you see how Title goes pink as-well as the bottom line.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Experementing</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
        body,html
        {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }

        label
        {
            font-size: 10px;
            color:grey;
        }
        label:focus
        {
            color:pink;
        }
        input
        {
            border-left: none;
            border-top: none;
            border-right: none;
            border-bottom: solid grey 1px;
            color:black;
            width:150px;
            height:auto;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        }
        /*Changes style when input box is clicked*/

        input:focus, textarea:focus, isindex:focus, keygen:focus, select:focus
        {

            border-left: none;
            border-top: none;
            border-right: none;
            border-bottom: solid pink 2px;
            outline: none;
        }
        :focus
        {
            color:pink;
        }

        /*removes the glow from auto form fill*/
        input:-webkit-autofill 
        {
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 50px white inset; /* Change the color to your own background color */
            -webkit-text-fill-color: #333;
        }

        input:-webkit-autofill:focus
        {
            -webkit-box-shadow: /*your box-shadow*/,0 0 0 50px white inset;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: #333;
        } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="username">Username<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="username"/></label>
    </div>

    <div  style="float:left; margin-left:10px;">
        <label for="pass">Password</label><br/>
        <input type="password" name="Nickname" id="pass"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="" name="login" style="background: url(sent.svg); border:none; background-size: cover cover; width:25px; height:25px;" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `<label>` after your `<input>` and then use the CSS sibling selector `~`.
You'll then need to move `<label>` visually back above `<input>` with `top:-4em;`.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c37eA/

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOPCC.png

If you don't want your input color to change (e.g. you want "Blah" to be black instead of pink), delete the rule:

```
:focus
{
  color:pink;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you don't know how long I spent trying to get it to work. thanks :)